# CalcCRC32 for 64-bit programs?

Tags: delphi, hash, delphi-10.1-berlin, crc32

I found this code in an older program from Angus Johnson:

```
const
  table:  ARRAY[0..255] OF DWORD =
 ($00000000, $77073096, $EE0E612C, $990951BA,
  $076DC419, $706AF48F, $E963A535, $9E6495A3,
  $0EDB8832, $79DCB8A4, $E0D5E91E, $97D2D988,
  $09B64C2B, $7EB17CBD, $E7B82D07, $90BF1D91,
  $1DB71064, $6AB020F2, $F3B97148, $84BE41DE,
  $1ADAD47D, $6DDDE4EB, $F4D4B551, $83D385C7,
  $136C9856, $646BA8C0, $FD62F97A, $8A65C9EC,
  $14015C4F, $63066CD9, $FA0F3D63, $8D080DF5,
  $3B6E20C8, $4C69105E, $D56041E4, $A2677172,
  $3C03E4D1, $4B04D447, $D20D85FD, $A50AB56B,
  $35B5A8FA, $42B2986C, $DBBBC9D6, $ACBCF940,
  $32D86CE3, $45DF5C75, $DCD60DCF, $ABD13D59,
  $26D930AC, $51DE003A, $C8D75180, $BFD06116,
  $21B4F4B5, $56B3C423, $CFBA9599, $B8BDA50F,
  $2802B89E, $5F058808, $C60CD9B2, $B10BE924,
  $2F6F7C87, $58684C11, $C1611DAB, $B6662D3D,

  $76DC4190, $01DB7106, $98D220BC, $EFD5102A,
  $71B18589, $06B6B51F, $9FBFE4A5, $E8B8D433,
  $7807C9A2, $0F00F934, $9609A88E, $E10E9818,
  $7F6A0DBB, $086D3D2D, $91646C97, $E6635C01,
  $6B6B51F4, $1C6C6162, $856530D8, $F262004E,
  $6C0695ED, $1B01A57B, $8208F4C1, $F50FC457,
  $65B0D9C6, $12B7E950, $8BBEB8EA, $FCB9887C,
  $62DD1DDF, $15DA2D49, $8CD37CF3, $FBD44C65,
  $4DB26158, $3AB551CE, $A3BC0074, $D4BB30E2,
  $4ADFA541, $3DD895D7, $A4D1C46D, $D3D6F4FB,
  $4369E96A, $346ED9FC, $AD678846, $DA60B8D0,
  $44042D73, $33031DE5, $AA0A4C5F, $DD0D7CC9,
  $5005713C, $270241AA, $BE0B1010, $C90C2086,
  $5768B525, $206F85B3, $B966D409, $CE61E49F,
  $5EDEF90E, $29D9C998, $B0D09822, $C7D7A8B4,
  $59B33D17, $2EB40D81, $B7BD5C3B, $C0BA6CAD,

  $EDB88320, $9ABFB3B6, $03B6E20C, $74B1D29A,
  $EAD54739, $9DD277AF, $04DB2615, $73DC1683,
  $E3630B12, $94643B84, $0D6D6A3E, $7A6A5AA8,
  $E40ECF0B, $9309FF9D, $0A00AE27, $7D079EB1,
  $F00F9344, $8708A3D2, $1E01F268, $6906C2FE,
  $F762575D, $806567CB, $196C3671, $6E6B06E7,
  $FED41B76, $89D32BE0, $10DA7A5A, $67DD4ACC,
  $F9B9DF6F, $8EBEEFF9, $17B7BE43, $60B08ED5,
  $D6D6A3E8, $A1D1937E, $38D8C2C4, $4FDFF252,
  $D1BB67F1, $A6BC5767, $3FB506DD, $48B2364B,
  $D80D2BDA, $AF0A1B4C, $36034AF6, $41047A60,
  $DF60EFC3, $A867DF55, $316E8EEF, $4669BE79,
  $CB61B38C, $BC66831A, $256FD2A0, $5268E236,
  $CC0C7795, $BB0B4703, $220216B9, $5505262F,
  $C5BA3BBE, $B2BD0B28, $2BB45A92, $5CB36A04,
  $C2D7FFA7, $B5D0CF31, $2CD99E8B, $5BDEAE1D,

  $9B64C2B0, $EC63F226, $756AA39C, $026D930A,
  $9C0906A9, $EB0E363F, $72076785, $05005713,
  $95BF4A82, $E2B87A14, $7BB12BAE, $0CB61B38,
  $92D28E9B, $E5D5BE0D, $7CDCEFB7, $0BDBDF21,
  $86D3D2D4, $F1D4E242, $68DDB3F8, $1FDA836E,
  $81BE16CD, $F6B9265B, $6FB077E1, $18B74777,
  $88085AE6, $FF0F6A70, $66063BCA, $11010B5C,
  $8F659EFF, $F862AE69, $616BFFD3, $166CCF45,
  $A00AE278, $D70DD2EE, $4E048354, $3903B3C2,
  $A7672661, $D06016F7, $4969474D, $3E6E77DB,
  $AED16A4A, $D9D65ADC, $40DF0B66, $37D83BF0,
  $A9BCAE53, $DEBB9EC5, $47B2CF7F, $30B5FFE9,
  $BDBDF21C, $CABAC28A, $53B39330, $24B4A3A6,
  $BAD03605, $CDD70693, $54DE5729, $23D967BF,
  $B3667A2E, $C4614AB8, $5D681B02, $2A6F2B94,
  $B40BBE37, $C30C8EA1, $5A05DF1B, $2D02EF8D);

//CRC algorithm courtesy of Earl F. Glynn ...
//(http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Mathematics/CRC.htm)
function CalcCRC32(p: pchar; length: integer): dword;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  result := $FFFFFFFF;
  for i := 0 to length-1 do
  begin
    result := (result shr 8) xor table[ pbyte(p)^ xor (result and $000000ff) ];
    inc(p);
  end;
  result := not result;
end;
```

The CalcCRC32 function gives back erroneous results if the code is compiled in 64-bit program.

How could this function be changed to make it work in a 64-bit program in Delphi 10.1 Berlin?

The code has been taken from: TextDiff\BasicDemo2\HashUnit.pas on http://www.angusj.com/delphi/textdiff.html

I have used these two texts to test TextDiff:

Text 1:

CompanyName=Igor Pavlov
FileDescription=7-Zip Standalone Console
FileVersion=17.01 beta
InternalName=7za
LegalCopyright=Copyright (c) 1999-2017 Igor Pavlov
OriginalFilename=7za.exe
ProductName=7-Zip
ProductVersion=17.01 beta

Text2:

CompanyName=Igor Pavlov
FileDescription=7-Zip Standalone Console
FileVersion=4.61 beta
InternalName=7za
LegalCopyright=Copyright (c) 1999-2008 Igor Pavlov
OriginalFilename=7za.exe
ProductName=7-Zip
ProductVersion=4.61 beta

Here is how I changed the code according to the solution:

```
function CalcCRC32(p: PByte; length: NativeUInt): dword;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  result := $FFFFFFFF;
  for i := 0 to length-1 do
  begin
    result := (result shr 8) xor table[ pbyte(p)^ xor (result and $000000ff) ];
    inc(p);
  end;
  result := not result;
end;

function HashLine(const line: string; IgnoreCase, IgnoreBlanks: boolean): pointer;
var
  i, j, len: integer;
  s: String;
begin
  s := line;
  if IgnoreBlanks then
  begin
    i := 1;
    j := 1;
    len := length(line);
    while i <= len do
    begin
      if not (line[i] in [#9,#32]) then
      begin
        s[j] := line[i];
        inc(j);
      end;
      inc(i);
    end;
    setlength(s,j-1);
  end;
  if IgnoreCase then s := AnsiLowerCase(s);
  //return result as a pointer to save typecasting later...
  result := pointer(CalcCRC32(PByte(s), length(s)));
end;
```

Comment: It's not going to be a 32/64 bit issue. It's going to be an ANSI/Unicode issue

Comment: You don't show in code how you use your examples.

Comment: Look in the edited question.

Comment: What is the definition of `s`?

Comment: s is a string..

Comment: My comment still stands. Do you know how your text is encoded?

Comment: You can download the source code.

Comment: @user1580348: If `s := 'Hello'` then `length(s) = 4` but it takes 8 bytes and contains the following values: $48, $00, $65, $00, $6C $00, $6C, $00, $6F, $00. For each character 2 bytes. I tested your `CalcCRC32(p: PByte; length: NativeUInt): Dword` on Berlin 10.1 Update 2 and my Win32 and Win64 console apps return the same value.

Comment: Please download the source code from Angus Johnson's page.

Comment: Since you didn't answer my question I presume you don't yet know about text encodings. It would pay to read up on that subject.

Comment: The source code to the TextDiff utility was never supposed to be published for the very reason it didn't behave when compiled with Wide chars and 64bit and much of the code was (and still is) a mess. I'm not sure how you got hold of this as generally I refuse requests to release it. Perhaps I relented with you. Anyhow, I've just rechecked my website and I can't see the source code there.

Comment: Ahhh, I've just seen the link to a very old zip file (mentioned and linked to above) that I didn't realise was still online. Yes, it does contain 2 very basic demos (not the TextDiff utility). Anyhow, they're 10 years old and won't work with unicode or 64bit compiling. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

In general, this code should work in 64bit, provided `length` does not exceed 2GB. That is not your issue.

The `p` parameter needs to be changed from `PChar` to `PByte` (or even just `Pointer`) since `PChar` is `PWideChar` in D2009+ but the code is expecting `PChar` to be `PAnsiChar` instead.

Also, you should probably change `length` from `Integer` to `Native(U)Int` so you can take better advantage of 64bit memory sizes greater than 2GB.

Now, with that said, if you want to get the CRC of a `string`, be aware that `string` is a UTF-16 encoded `UnicodeString` in D2009+, but CRC operates on *bytes* rather than *characters*. So, when computing the CRC of a `string`, you have to decide which byte encoding it should be converted to first. And when comparing the CRCs of multiple strings, make sure they are converted to the same byte encoding first.

Comment: The code still does not work. It has been taken from Angus Johnson's TextDiff\BasicDemo2: http://www.angusj.com/delphi/textdiff.html

Comment: @user1580348 the code works fine. You are just not taking Unicode into account correctly. The original code was written for a Delphi version that predated Unicode.

Comment: Thank you Remy, I understand this now. How could Angus Johnson's code be made Unicode-aware?

Comment: Don't pass text to the function. Pass bytes, binary data. Start with text, encode using your chosen encoding, e.g. UTF8, then pass those bytes to the CRC function

Answer (score 1):

You may read the [following](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.UnicodeString) to better understand how `string` works in Delphi.

Here you have the `interface` section of an unicode aware `HashLine` function; there is no reason to use `Pointer` as the result type.

```
uses System.Types;

function HashLine(const line: string; IgnoreCase, IgnoreBlanks: boolean): dword;
```

Here the `implementation` part.

```
uses
  System.SysUtils, System.StrUtils, System.Character, System.Classes;


const
  table:  ARRAY[0..255] OF DWORD =
 ($00000000, $77073096, $EE0E612C, $990951BA,
  ...
  $B40BBE37, $C30C8EA1, $5A05DF1B, $2D02EF8D);

function CalcCRC32(p: PByte; length: NativeUInt): DWORD;
var
  i: NativeUInt;
begin
  result := $FFFFFFFF;
  for i := 0 to length-1 do
  begin
    result := (result shr 8) xor table[ p^ xor (result and $000000ff) ];
    inc(p);
  end;
  result := not result;
end;

function HashLine(const line: string; IgnoreCase, IgnoreBlanks: boolean): DWORD;
var
  i, j: integer;
  s: string;
  b: TBytes;
begin
  if IgnoreBlanks then
  begin
    j := low(string);
    setlength(s, length(line));
    for i := low(line) to high(line) do
    begin
      // if not (line[i] in [#9,#32]) then
      if not line[i].IsWhiteSpace() then
      begin
        s[j] := line[i];
        inc(j);
      end;
    end;
    setlength(s,j-1);
  end else begin
    s := line;
  end;

  if IgnoreCase then
    s := s.ToLower();

  b := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);

  result := CalcCRC32(@b[0], length(b));
end;
```

The call `HashLine('HEllo, World!', false, false)` results `F47B1828` which is equal to the result [here](http://www.crc32generator.de/)

Comment: This looks very interesting and promising. I will test it tomorrow after having put my body to rest.

Comment: Sorry for being late, I caught a heavy cold, still being affected. Understood your idea. But how would you integrate this into the whole *TextDiff* project? Since `procedure TForm1.BuildHashList` in Unit1.pas for example expects a `Pointer` parameter and now gets a `DWORD`.

Comment: @user1580348: That may be a new question, but after Angus Johnson last comment **...and much of the code was (and still is) a mess...** at your question, you may take another approach at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `result := not result;` to `result := result xor $FFFFFFFF;`.